# Co-ordinates are not passed to main loop through mousecallback function in python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm newbie in python and i want to learn python. The code(below) is as same as the code i have written in C++. The code works fine in C++ but in python it's not.
My concern is when i hold mouse left button it should draw a circle on image but it's not.
Any help would be appreciated.

code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

class mouse_state:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = [-1,-1]
        self.left_button_held = False
        self.left_button_clicked = False

    def new_iteration():
        left_button_clicked = False
    

def mouse_callback(event, x,y, flag, param):
    param = mouse_state()

    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        param.position = (x,y)
        param.left_button_held = True
        print('LMB Down @ ', param.position)

    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        param.position = (x,y)
        param.left_button_held = False
        param.left_button_clicked = True
        print('LMB Up @ ', param.position)

    elif (flag == cv.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON) and (event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE):
        param.position = (x,y)
        print('LMB Held, Mouse Moved To',param.position)


cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
assert cap.isOpened()
windowName = 'Feed'
cv.namedWindow(windowName)
ms = mouse_state()
cv.setMouseCallback(windowName, mouse_callback, ms)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret: break
    (height, width) = frame.shape[:2]

    if ms.left_button_clicked or ms.left_button_held:
        cv.circle(frame, ms.position, 3, (0,0,255))
        cv.circle(frame, ms.position, 10, (255,0,0), 2)
        print('Current Position ', ms.position)

    ms.new_iteration
    
    cv.imshow(windowName, frame)
    w = cv.waitKey(1)
    if w == ord('q'):
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do any of your print statements go off when you click? Or does nothing happen?

Comment: Hi @jarcobi889, The function mouse_callback works fine. Only if condition in while loop is not working. And yes it prints LMB Down, LMP Up and LMB Held.

Comment: you try to pass an instance of your class as the "param" but then, in the callback, you throw that away and create a new instance??